# How to know if a company uses User Logon Name Pre-windows 2000 (SamAccount) or the new User Logon name , to authenticate their users

Tags: windows-7, windows, active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication

If users login to their windows machines by entering the following on the Windows login screen:

> Domainname\username
>
> Password

Does this mean that the company uses the User Logon Name format from Pre-windows 2000 , and not the new User Logon Name, since we enter the following **Domainname\username** and not **username@domainname** ?

Comment: domain\username is not a retired format by any means, and is completely supported by NTLM and NTLMv2 networks. it is not an indication that a network uses LANMAN.

Comment: @FrankThomas so what indicates if a company uses User Logon Name Pre-windows 2000 (SamAccount) or the new User Logon name , to authenticate their users?